# Remote Access from wLAN to LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

Sorry this is probably a newb question but I need some direction on this issue. If on my home network I have a machine directly wired to router from my ISP, how can I allow machines on my Wireless LAN see it? I can't even ping this machine from the wireless. Any help would be much appreciated.

Update: Just noticed this on my router. The device list on the router has a list of IP's with `xxx.xxx.1.xx`. The machine I just connected on the ethernet has an IP of `xxx.xxx.56.xx`. The device list on the router config shows both wireless and ethernet connected devices. Is this part of the issue?

Comment: Home networking is offtopic here.  Superuser might be a better fit foe this question.

Comment: Do you have two routers on your network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys this turned out to be a total newb error. This computer was still connected through the wireless. The IP I was referring to was the IP from whatever virtual network Virtual Box creates when you install it. The machine had a IP for the wireless bc thats what it was connected through. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, that is why you cannot see your machine.  It is not on the same network.  You have a couple of options.
1. Change its IP to something on your network, does this need to be static, if so make sure it is outside your DHCP range.  This is the easiest of them all.
2. Add a second IP to the nic of your other machines, this will allow cross network communication.
3. create a route across the networks with your router.  I would not advise this as you are having issues currently with this machine.

To have machines see each other on a typical network, the first three octects have to mactch.  for example 192.168.0.X.  The only number that can change is the last number denoted by the X.  Addidionally it cannot be 0 or equal to or above 255